# RabbitMQ - security/authentication

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm working on an application, and I'm just wondering is it possible for RabbitMQ to allow all clients to push messages to a specific queue and only authenticated users to consume messages from that queue? I can't seem to find anything about this :/

Basicly my model is like this:
Clients all connect to same queue and push their messages on it. Also each client should register it's own queue where he recieves messages (each client has unique queue).

So basicly clients would send messages to one queue, and ONLY my server application should be able to read from it, process data and send reply to the specific user queue (which should be read ONLY by that user and ONLY server shoud publish on it).

I guess this is possible right? Can someone steer me in the right direction where to find more info on those things/examples/tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it is not possible AFAIK out of box, but you have 2 options:

1. You can write own plugin for rabbitmq if you familiar with erlang (that's don't need extra erlang knowledge - just basics)
2. You can create 2 virtual hosts and exchange on each host (vhost A for read vhost B for write). In virtual host B create exchange, and bind it to particular queue using routing key. In virtual host A create federated exchange[1]. Brief: federated exchange allows map exchange to upstream exchange, it means, that mapped exchange will receive all messages from upstream exchange. So make exchange E1 in virtual host A and map it to exchange E2 in virtual host B. For each virtual host you can create different users.

[1]: http://www.rabbitmq.com/federation.html - it's manual about federation plugin, that contains ready-to-go examples.

Comment: So there is no simpler way to prevent unauthorized access? I hope you see my concern here, as I want to assure that my few worker nodes getting messages from a queue and processing them, would get the messages, if someone else figured the way to connect to that same queue i would be loosing some of the messages that would've been recieved by them.

And queue should be able to recieve messages from everybody, since client app would be hosted on user devices.

Comment: Sorry there is simpler way:) If you are using management plugin (http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html), you can go to Virtual Hosts tab, and add users, there are fields "write regexp" and "read regexp" you can pass here you queue names.
Or you can use "set_permissions" command from rabbitmqctl.